# Proxmoxer required for this module

Tags: ansible, proxmox, lxd

I keep getting this error when try create ProxMox containers using Ansible. Has anyone know how to fix this? Im trying to create Proxmox VE cluster containers. Uses LXD containers.

> Here is my playbook

```html
- hosts: proxmox
  user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Test container
      proxmox:
        vmid: 777
        node: 'pve'
        api_user: 'root@pam'
        api_password: 'admin'
        api_host: 'node1'
        password: '123456'
        hostname: 'example.org'
        ostemplate: 'local:vztmpl/ubuntu-16.04-standard_16.04-1_amd64.tar.gz'
```

> Here is complete Ansible debug report

```
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_p2azl7/ansible_module_proxmox.py", line 325, in <module>
    from proxmoxer import ProxmoxAPI

fatal: [proxmox]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_host": "node1",
            "api_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "api_user": "root@pam",
            "cores": 1,
            "cpus": 1,
            "cpuunits": 1000,
            "disk": "3",
            "force": false,
            "hostname": "example.org",
            "ip_address": null,
            "memory": 512,
            "mounts": null,
            "nameserver": null,
            "netif": null,
            "node": "pve",
            "onboot": false,
            "ostemplate": "local:vztmpl/ubuntu-16.04-standard_16.04-1_amd64.tar.gz",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "pool": null,
            "pubkey": null,
            "searchdomain": null,
            "state": "present",
            "storage": "local",
            "swap": 0,
            "timeout": 30,
            "unprivileged": false,
            "validate_certs": false,
            "vmid": "777"
        }
    },
    "msg": "proxmoxer required for this module"
}
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [proxmoxer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/proxmoxer) on `proxmox` machine.

Or otherwise explain, what is your expectation for trying to run it without the library. You might be running it on a different target than you intended.